# fmincon: Problem with the optimization of the MPC

Tags: matlab, optimization

I try to use an economic MPC for urban traffic (modelled as a state space system), to control the intersection's light. 
I use `fmincon` for the optimization. 
When I simulate it, I find that the `fmincon` runs more than one time for every sample time: for the first sample time, `fmincon` runs 32 times, the control value changes and Matlab shows me this message:

Initial point is a local minimum that satisfies the constraints.

Optimization completed because at the initial point, the objective function is non-decreasing in feasible directions to within the default value of the optimality tolerance, and constraints are satisfied to within the default value of the constraint tolerance.

stopping criteria details

After that, `fmincon` runs 2 times, the control value stays the same with the same matlab message.
Can I limit this run's number?

Answer (score 0):

OK, you mixed-up a couple of topics:

**MPC** That stands for *model predictive control*, which is a control technique that solves an optimization problem at every sample point for a defined future horizon (by this it determines the control law implicitly, so you don't need to do the nasty pole-placement in Laplacian-space).

Anyway, you use `fmincon` to solve this optimization problem. If you go for runtime (so if it is a real-controller and not just a simulation) this is a bad choice since you have just a (potentially constrained but) **linear optimization** problem (state-space representation as you noted). Have a look here at Matlab doc on [how to choose the ideal algorithm](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/choosing-the-algorithm.html). For real implementations, I suggest to use the open-source library [NLopt](https://nlopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which provides a nice Matlab interface and typically runs faster.

**fmincon** Now to your actual question: can one limit the calls of the objective function in `fmincon`? (Note that your term "*run*" is confusing as this refers to the starting of the optimization... as one would to over and over again in MPC. But you wanted to say "*call of the objective function*" as I guess)
The answer is yes.

```
opts = optimoptions('fmincon','MaxFunctionEvaluations',100);
[x,fval,exitflag] = fmincon(fun,x0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,nonlcon,opts)
```

Without code, it is hard to follow your specific problem, but the message (and probalb the `exitflag`) tells you that either your initial value or your objective-function sucks. `fmincon` doesn't find a direction in your parameter space, in which it can step for decreasing the value of your objective-function. The number of function-calls when it raisis this warning depends on the number of parameters `length(x0)` as the algorithm first needs wiggle a little at all parameters in all directions...

Comment: Thank you very much Max for your help! Can I contact you directly to present you all?

Comment: @IlyasKH make a MVE (minimum valuable example) and turn the question in a general form. So that others can follow your problem more easy and can learn something from the answers here

Comment: Thank you very much @max for your help and all this suggestion and information. About the controller, I use a real time simulation software with Matlab. 
About the MPC, I use a non linear model, you can find the description here: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0968090X12000150
You're right about "call of the objective function", it's not "run".
Your find in the answer the function that I use for **fmincon**:

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much @max for your help and all this suggestion and information. About the controller, I use a real time simulation software with Matlab.

About the MPC, I use a non linear model, you can find the description here: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0968090X12000150

You're right about "call of the objective function", it's not "run".

I test the option that you suggest, the simulation is the same (same messages, same situation) I think that the problem is related with the number of "call of the objective function" for every sample time, not the number of the use of **fmincon** at all the simulation.

Your find below the function that I use for **fmincon**:

function u = solve(Np,x0,u0,Nu,q,ii)

```
u0 = [0];
Cycletime= 20/3600;

A =   [];
b =   [];
Aeq = [];
beq = [];
lb =  [];
ub =  [];
lbx = [];
ubx = [];
lbu = [];
ubu = [];

lx = 0;
ux = 386;
lu = 0;
uu = Cycletime;

lbx = [lbx, lx];
ubx = [ubx, ux];
lbu = [lbu lu];
ubu = [ubu uu];

 lb = [lbu ;lbx]; 
 ub = [ubu ;ubx];

% Solve optimization problem

u = fmincon(@(u)costfunction1(x0,u,Nu,Np,q,ii), u0, A, b, Aeq, beq, lb,ub) ;
```

end